# Terminus (or any other bitmap font) blurry on HiDPI

Tags: fonts, cinnamon, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator, fontconfig

I'm using an UHD screen and have everything set to be 2x scaled (Cinnamon DE, Arch Linux).
I would like to use a bitmap font that is not anti-aliased, i. e. pixelated, for my terminal emulator (gnome-terminal, but I'd be glad to use another one if necessary). I use the Terminus font on my Full HD laptop, which looks great, and I want to recreate that look on my UHD monitor. Unfortunately, it looks very blurry. There's a TTF version of the font, but it looks very different at the "same" (2x) size (12) at UHD. The TTF version looks perfect if I set it to 6. Is there a way to scale that version of the font to size 12 using integer scaling?